# How to find the newly added files in Git repo using pydriller

Tags: python, git

I am able to find out the files which have been modified in the Git repo but this piece of code is not returning the files which have been newly added, can anyone please help me to update the code so that the newly added files can be identified.

```
from pydriller import Repository
for commit in Repository('path/to/the/repo').traverse_commits():
  for m in commit.modified_files:
    print("Modified file {}".format(m.filename))
```

For example, Between commit1 and commit5 there are 3 files modified and 2 newly added

```
M       changelog1.txt
M       newfile2.txt
M       changelog3.txt
A       changelog4.txt
A       newfile5.txt
```

With the code above it's returning all the files which have been modified, but not the ones which have been added.

PS: I am also open to any other solution

Comment: By "the files which have been newly added", do you mean in the last commit, or `git add`ed but not yet committed? What does this code output, and what exactly would you like it to output instead? Ideally, show a minimal reproducible example, with the minimal commands needed to create the context and the output you expect in that context. Then it'll be a lot easier to answer your question.

Comment: @joanis : I updated the Question , hope  this will help

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. When I run your code, it's showing my both added and modified files. If you do `print("File {} change_type {}".format(m.filename, m.change_type)` it should show you more clearly what it's listing for you. In my test, though, it's showing my the commits from oldest to more recent, which I did not expect.

Comment: @joanis , Thanks for your valuable time seems like it is working fine already, I was doing some typo in Dates , I can see Modified and Added both the files ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added and Modified both the files are picked  by `Repository('path/to/the/repo').traverse_commits():`

In order to view the status of the modified file we just need to use m.change_type like mentioned in the below example

```
print("File {} change_type {}".format(m.filename, m.change_type)
```